# mySQL combining data from 2 databases

Tags: mysql, database, merge

### The Problem.

I have a website which was recently switched over to a new server php/mysql.

Its an e-commerce site, when it was switched over the person who did the switch did not switch over the database for all the pages on the site, so I have some data that exists on both mysql databases (the new and old server), and some data that exists on the old server but not on the new server and vice versa.

I need to merge the data from the 2 databases into one database with all the data.

### My solution:

I am thinking the best way to go about this is too write a php script that gets the data from the old server, checks to see if the fields (other than the primary id) exists on the new server, if the record does not exist then insert it into the new table on the new server.

The structure is not so complex, but the orders table has a look-up field to the order details table (using the primary key of the orders table as the foreign key)

Any ideas on an easier quicker way to do this, is there something in phpmyadmin that can merge two databases?

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could create another table using the federated storage engine on your new server.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/federated-usagenotes.html

Then you can have access to both within single sql queries.
Assuming you have privileges to allow other hosts to connect to your old server.

Comment: thanks for that, is an intresting feature i didnt know existed, i dont think it will work for my problem as the daabase on the old server will not continue to remain online, so i need to consolidate the data into 1 database